# Código SQL com php PDO bindValue retorna uma aspas simples dentro do IN no SQL

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Seguinte, estou desenvolvendo um sistema de combustível, especificamente na parte de de filtros para geração de um relatório personalizado ele me retorna um IN('1,2,3') com aspas simples

Tudo se inicia no formulário, no qual eu tenho um multiselect que quando enviado via POST ele me retorna da seguinte forma:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "41" [1]=> string(2) "42" [2]=> string(2) "43" }
```

Então eu utilizo uma trait para tratar esses dados que se chama tratarSqlIn($dados)

```
public function tratarSqlIn($dados)
{
   $valor = implode(',', $dados);

    return $valor;
}
```

que retorna:

```
string(8) "41,42,43"
```

e utilizo ela dentro do FPDF:

```
$motoristas = TratarDados::tratarSqlIn($_POST['motorista']);

Assim ela é enviada para a model:

$saida->setMotorista($motoristas);

O SQL na model é da seguinte forma:


$sql = "SELECT *, a.quantidade, a.data_hora FROM ".$objClass->tabela." a
                INNER JOIN tbtanque b ON (b.id_tanque = a.id_tanque)
                INNER JOIN tbmotorista c ON (c.id_motorista = a.id_motorista)
                INNER JOIN tbveiculo d ON (d.id_veiculo = a.id_veiculo)  
            WHERE a.id_cliente = ".$_SESSION['id_cliente']."
            AND a.id_tanque IN(:tanques) AND a.id_motorista IN(:motoristas) AND a.id_veiculo IN(:veiculos) AND 
            a.data_hora BETWEEN :data_inicial AND :data_final AND a.flag_excluido = 0 ORDER BY a.id_saida DESC";
        
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':tanques', $objClass->getTanque(), \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':motoristas', $objClass->getMotorista(), \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':veiculos', $objClass->getVeiculo(), \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':data_inicial', $objClass->getDataInicial(), \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':data_final', $objClass->getDataFinal(), \PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stmt->execute();

        $objResultado = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $objResultado;
```

Utilizando antes do $stmt->execute()

```
$stmt->debugDumpParams();
exit;
```

Me retorna assim, dentro do IN( possui aspas simples):

```
SELECT *, a.quantidade, a.data_hora FROM tbmov_saida a 
INNER JOIN tbtanque b ON (b.id_tanque = a.id_tanque) 
INNER JOIN tbmotorista c ON (c.id_motorista = a.id_motorista)
INNER JOIN tbveiculo d ON (d.id_veiculo = a.id_veiculo) WHERE a.id_cliente = 11 
AND a.id_tanque IN('77,78') 
AND a.id_motorista IN('41,42,43')
AND a.id_veiculo IN('1,2') 
AND a.data_hora BETWEEN '2020-07-01 12:00:00' AND '2020-07-31 12:00:00'
AND a.flag_excluido = 0 ORDER BY a.id_saida DESC
```

O que eu sei: EU sei que o bindValue já insere os escapes e também não funciona pois já tentei com esse código na trait

```
public function tratarSqlIn($dados) { $valor = implode(',', $dados);

$explode_seq = explode(',', $valor);

$n = array();
foreach ($explode_seq as $num){
    $n[] = "'" . $num . "'";
}
$result = implode(" , ", $n);

return $result;

}
```

e isso fica `IN('\'2\',\'3\'')...`

Como remover essas apas simples?

Comment: aqui nesse link tem várias soluções para isso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767530/php-using-pdo-with-in-clause-array

Comment: Não ajudou muito.

Comment: Precisa estudar mais ... não ajudou porque você não quer ser ajudado, mas, sim quer pronto.

Comment: O conceito de ajudar é bem abstrato para você afirmar isto.

Comment: Então, reafirmo ... estude mais.

Comment: O problema não é estudar, eu já sabia o motivo e a solução foi a seguinte:  IN(".implode(',', $objClass->getMotorista() ).")  em cada IN no sql, pois o bindValue ele insere automaticamente dentro de aspas simples uma string. Obrigado pela sua colaboração.

Comment: Usando PDO::PARAM_STR faz isso mesmo... neste caso não precisa usar o bindValue, gera manualmente mesmo! O origem dos dados é segura!

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver, eu apenas adicionei dentro de casa IN o implode ex:

```
 IN(".implode(',', $objClass->getMotorista() ).")
```

O motivo é que o bindValue insere automaticamente uma cadeia de aspas simples entre a string.